# Change C array element via Rust FFI

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm using Rust to test some C code:

**lol.c**

```c
#include "lol.h"
int a[10]; //Assume lol.h has an extern declaration for a[10]
```

**lib.rs**

```
extern "C" {
    static a: *mut i32;
}

fn set_a(val: i32, index: usize) {
    assert!(index < 10);
    unsafe {
        a[index] = val;
    }
}

fn get_a(index: usize) {
    assert!(index < 10);
    unsafe { a[index] }
}
```

I used [the cc crate](https://crates.io/crates/cc) to compile and link lol.o. How do I write the `set_a` and `get_a` functions? The compiler says:

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `*mut i32`
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         a[index] = val;
  |         ^^^^^^^^

error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `*mut i32`
  --> src/main.rs:14:14
   |
14 |     unsafe { a[index] }
   |              ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Aside: the Rust equivalent of C's `int` is **not** `i32`; it's `c_int` in the [`libc`](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`offset`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset) method to find a single element, or use [`std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html) to create a slice from pointer and (possibly dynamic) length, or use `static mut a: *mut [i32; 10]` in the first place (use `(*a)[index]` to use it).

But: I'm pretty sure that `int a[10];` from `C` doesn't export a location of a pointer to that array, it exports the location of the array (i.e the location of the first element), and `extern` in Rust expects a location to a value of the given type (i.e. it is implemented as a pointer on both sides) , so I'd try this:

```
extern "C" {
    static mut a: [i32; 10];
}

fn set_a(val: i32, index: usize) {
    unsafe {
        a[index] = val;
    }
}

fn get_a(index: usize) -> i32 {
    unsafe { a[index] }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
a.offset(x) as *mut i32
```

Like this:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::malloc;
use std::mem::size_of;

unsafe fn zero(data: *mut u32, length: usize) {
    for i in 0..length - 1 {
        let ptr = data.offset(i as isize) as *mut u32;
        *ptr = 0;
    }
}

unsafe fn set(data: *mut u32, offset: usize, value: u32) {
    let ptr = data.offset(offset as isize) as *mut u32;
    *ptr = value;
}

unsafe fn get(data: *mut u32, offset: usize) -> u32 {
    let ptr = data.offset(offset as isize) as *mut u32;
    return *ptr;
}

unsafe fn alloc(length: usize) -> *mut u32 {
    let raw = malloc(length * size_of::<*mut u32>());
    return raw as *mut u32;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let data = alloc(10);
        zero(data, 10);

        println!("{:?}", get(data, 4));

        set(data, 4, 100);
        println!("{:?}", get(data, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two questions? Is the usize to isize because C indexing is different from Rust? Also why did you have to malloc. The space is already allocated in C right?

Comment: @KDN malloc was just an example (the code above runs on play.rust-lang.org). Obviously in your situation there's no need to malloc. The usize thing is because it's legal in C (and meaningful sometimes) to use x[-1]; so offset() can take a -ve number. In this case it's not meaningful to allow -ve values, so I made it usize instead of isize, but it's arbitrary. Just use isize if you don't care.